# Use iTerm2 as X11 terminal (for fonts, themes, etc)?

Tags: macos, x11, quartz-graphics, iterm2, x11-forwarding

I have to use Quartz X11 window when I want to plot data that is on a remote server (using NX). I'd like to use my iTerm terminal as the interface to this, as it is nicely customized with fonts, themes, etc - instead of the bare xterm window. How do I do this?

Comment: iTerm2 is a native OSX application, not X11

Comment: Perhaps the question is meant to ask how to use iTerm2 to run ssh.

Comment: I use iTerm2 when I ssh and I don't need the graphical component, that works fine. If my question is impossible, an alternative would be "How do I get my themes/fonts/etc" from iTerm2 into the Quartz X11 terminal. It doesn't seem to give me any customization options

Comment: It is all done with X11 resources (no themes).  Some people have collections of text files (or scripts) which setup particular themes.

Answer (score 20):

Assuming that you have set-up everything correctly with ssh and XQuartz. You need to set-up the `DISPLAY` environmental variable:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
ssh -Y ...
# start your app
```

xterm has variable `DISPLAY` automatically set by default.

Comment: Argh, after wasting time on other suggestions, this simple solution worked. Thanks!

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me. Also just in case it isn't clear, `export DISPLAY=:0` should be run in iTerm2 on Mac, not the remote window! I was stupid

Answer (score 3):

iTerm2 now works nicely with XQuartz (I have version 2.7.11). When XQuartz is running, I just need to use "ssh -Y" to enable X11 forwarding. If you run into a problem, try upgrading XQuartz, reboot (or log out and re-login), open XQuartz, then try connecting with iterm2.

Comment: Is there any way that does not require having a separate instance of XQuartz running?

Comment: Can I use `ssh -X` instead of `ssh -Y`?

Comment: @alper basically yes, see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/35512/what-is-the-difference-between-ssh-y-trusted-x11-forwarding-and-ssh-x-u